# Is it possible to set 'expr' and 'unit' from mysql INTERVAL using the query rows?

Tags: mysql

I'm expanding a booking system.

I have a set of records whom only should show in the results when the `START_DATE_VALUE` is an X amount of time in the future. Each of these records carries this value (`number` and `unit`, so `number`: `7` and `unit` `'DAY'` for example).

If the `INTERVAL` would be a fixed value, the following would be the solution.

`unix_timestamp('START_DATE_VALUE') > unix_timestamp(NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY)`

I would like to set have the `7` and `DAY` value from the `items` record, like so:

`unix_timestamp('FROM_DATE_VALUE') > unix_timestamp(NOW() + INTERVAL items.available_from_number items.available_from_unit)`

Simple version of the query to check availability of items:

```
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE items.id NOT IN (SELECT booking_items.item_id FROM bookings
    INNER JOIN booking_items ON bookings.id = booking_items.booking_id
    WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(bookings.end_date) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('START_DATE_VALUE')
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(bookings.start_date) <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('END_DATE_VALUE'));
```

I've been playing around for a while and I can't seem to figure it out. Is this at all possible with `mysql`?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch It will create a scary looking query, but it will help me solve the issue, thanks! After that I will need to translate it to Laraval Eloquent ORM. That'll be a great next challenge :)

Comment: Number may be inserted directly as `table.column`. Unit cannot - CASE is the simplest solution. `unix_timestamp('FROM_DATE_VALUE') > unix_timestamp(NOW() + CASE items.available_from_unit WHEN 'YEAR' THEN INTERVAL items.available_from_number YEAR WHEN 'MONTH' THEN INTERVAL items.available_from_number MONTH WHEN 'WEEK' THEN INTERVAL items.available_from_number WEEK WHEN 'DAY' THEN INTERVAL items.available_from_number DAY ELSE 0 END)`